# Send state through React route

Tags: react-router

How can I send a state through the route with react-router?
At the moment I change the route with this.context.router.push.
Is there another  possibility?

```
      this.context.router.push({
            pathname: '/EmpReferralListView',
            state: {
                message: (typeof message != 'undefined') ? message : ''
            }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to programatically change the route, push is your best option. Otherwise you can use standard [Link](http://knowbody.github.io/react-router-docs/api/Link.html) element.